# Background image repeated twice when reloading the page

Tags: symfony

Within **Symfony 4** (I don't know if this problem exists in the early versions). I have a very strange and annoying issue. I want to load a background image (later I will change this to a bootstrap carousel). But for now it is very irritating when I use, for instance, a registration form on the same background with route (annotations). 
Like /edit, /register, /login, etc. 
It looks like the background image shows twice! So when you switch to a login screen. The background image on the back is blinking when rending the page!

How can I fix this?

I have disabled twig cache. But it does not seem to work with 
   `cache: false`

This is my Symfony 4 controller code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/bg_image")
 */
public function bg_image()
{
    return $this->render('base.html.twig', ['text' => 'next']);
}

/**
 * @Route("/bg_image/next_page")
 */
public function next_page()
{
    return $this->render('base.html.twig', ['text' => 'next']);
}

/**
 * @Route("/bg_image/prev_page")
 */
public function prev_page()
{
    return $this->render('base.html.twig', ['text' => 'prev']);
}
```

This is my Symfony 4 twig template "base.html.twig":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/custom.css">
        {% endblock %} 
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="/images/slide.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="200">
        <h1 class="top-left">{{ text }}</h1>
        <br/><br/>
        <a href="/bg_image/next_page">next</a> |
        <a href="/bg_image/prev_page">prev</a>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I want a smooth transition instead of blinking between the prev and next page like this example.

It is a Symfony framework issue I guess. When I build this page without Symfony. No blinking occurs.

Comment: what's the aim of having an action `bg_image` and `next_page` that does exactly the same ? I think you are using it the wrong way. maybe if you tell us what you're trying to achieve we could help/guide you better.

Comment: That's correct. This is only an example where you easily see what is going on. The reload of a page will also caused this strange behaviour of showing the image for 10px and blanc out the rest. And direct after that the whole image. This will happend all in a split second. But gives a strange blinking

Comment: To see what I mean in action! 
Check (https://steenksonline.nl/symfony/home) and (https://www.steenksonline.nl/apache/)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with Symfony.

The background image sometimes looks like it disappears and then re-appears when you click "next" or "prev", then it's because you're requesting a new page. When it stops doing that, it's because your browser has cached the page and it's loading the new page so fast that you don't see the change with your naked eye.

If you want a "smooth transition" in-page between changing elements, you'll need to use Javascript/CSS to manipulate the elements without requesting a new page.